# Codeigniter uri undefined. Broken on home page, fine on search page

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, uri

I have a site set up where there is a route for profile/username that goes to page/profile/username

I set up a bunch of results on the home page that link to profile/username. When you click one of those links the url has undefined as one of the segments. But if you click the same link from the search results page, it works fine. This is best seen by just looking at the site...

The url is http://www.findtheguides.com. If you look towards the bottom, and you click to visit one of their profiles, you'll see the uri segment is undefined and there are errors displaying.

If you go to the search page here: http://www.findtheguides.com/page/start_search and you click to visit one of their profiles, it works completely fine.

In both instances i'm sending using the code:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('profile/'.$guide['username']); ?>">view profile</a>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: plz share the code for the home page and profile page..

Comment: user3114651 wants to know "are u putting the username in session?" in case his "answer" gets deleted.

Comment: are u putting the username in session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll see that you're javascript code is this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.featured-profile', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var username = $(this).attr('data-username');
  window.location.replace(siteUrl+"profile/"+username);
});
```

And looking at the element that corresponds to `this` (the `div` with class `featured-profile`), you'll see that there is no `data-username` attribute at all.

This is your problem.